# store large data python

Tags: python, arrays, large-data

I am new with Python. Recenty,I have a project which processing huge amount of health data in xml file. 
Here is an example:

[image]

In my data, there is about 100 of them and each of them have different id, origin, type and text . I want to store in data all of them so that I could training this dataset, the first idea in my mind was to use 2D arry ( one stores id and origin the other stores text). However, I found there are too many features and I want to know which features belong to each document.

Could anyone recommend a best way to do it.

Comment: You can probably get away with a dictionary with id as key and either a dictionary (with features as keys and their values as values) or an object as the value.

Comment: I copied the image into your question, but it's best to post relevant code using `{ }` rather than image.

Comment: As far as your problem, I would suggest using xml parsing packages to obtain the data where you can either import into dictionary or possible dataframe. The way it stand right now, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scalability ,simplicity and maintainance, you should normalised those data, build a database schema and move those stuff into database (sqlite,postgres,mysql,whatever)

This will move complicate data logic out of python. This is a typical practice of Model-view-controller.

Create a python dictionary and traverse it are quick and dirty. It will become huge technical time sink very soon if you want to make practical sense out of the data.